# Shared folder disappear after virtual machine shutdown

Tags: virtualbox, mount, ubuntu-14.04, shared-folders

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox 5.0.24 r108355.

I mount my folder with command:

```
mkdir my_folder
sudo mount -t vboxsf my_folder /home/user/my_folder
```

In VirtualBox settings (Devices->Shared fodlers->Shared folders settings) I have `Auto-mount` and `Make Permanent` folders checked.

When I close and reopen my VM shared folder is not mounted and I need to perform `sudo mount -t vboxsf my_folder /home/user/my_folder` once more time.

So how to make shared folder mounting permanent?

Comment: Do you have the VBox Guest Additions installed?

Comment: @Seth I think yes, how to check it? When I setup VM I have used `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils`.

Comment: What version of VirutalBox are you running? You might've installed "old" Utilities. See also [this help article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm).

Comment: @Seth As I said `VirtualBox 5.0.24 r108355`

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Anyway did you try to install current vbox additions instead of the one from the Repo? [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/GuestAdditions) would be an official Wiki entry on how to do it (last part). Going by [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/virtualbox-guest-utils) it would seem the version you installed is for VBox 4.3.36(?).

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this, @mrgloom?

Answer (score 1):

Shared folder auto mounting chooses an "auto" mount point; it will not miraculously use some particular mount point you yourself used at some particular moment.

The VirtualBox Guest Additions auto mount point for Linux is composed of a prefix, */media/sf_* by default, prepended to the name under which you share the folder in VirtualBox. You can change the prefix to */home/user/* with a VboxManage command:

```
 VBoxManage guestproperty set <vm> /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix /home/user/
```

where  is the name or UUID of your virtual machine. Because a virtual machine only has a single such prefix, it would apply to all auto-mounted shared folders of that virtual machine.